# Stop spam in the form of invitations

Tags: outlook.com, spam-prevention, office-365

Nowadays, besides receiving quite some spam e-mail, I am seeing spam invitations on my Windows Live network. I haven't seen these people ever before, I'm 100% sure they are some spam people trying to attract men by using those sexy pictures, which is annoying as I don't expect nor want this.

Is there any way to stop this?

<sub>I'm already blocking all incoming invitations from this kind of person.</sub>

Sample screenshots (Dutch version as I'm Dutch):

[image: spam]